# In vb.net, what does the ! operator after DataRow do?

Tags: vb.net

Everyone, what does the "!" after the DataRow Object means? And why DataRow can get ColumnName Attribute?

```
Sub constructAttrMeta(ByVal objRows As DataRow)
        Try
            setColName(objRows!ColumnName.ToString)
            ...
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception
        End Try
End Sub


Sub setColName(ByVal sColName As String)
        Me.m_sColName = sColName.ToUpper
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it !